# How does casting work and reffering back to the parent

Tags: actionscript, parent, program-entry-point, timeline

I cant get my head around this. I was looking at the lynda.com ActionScript 3.0 in Flash Professional CS5 Essential Training. I understand all the other stuff, but this guy places a skater on the stage he has this code on the first frame on the main timeline:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var boarder:MovieClip = boarder_mc;
boarder.stop();
boarder.x = 0;
boarder.y = 0;
boarder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedBoarder);

function clickedBoarder(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    boarder.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function restart():void
{
    boarder_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    boarder_mc.x = 0;
}
```

then on the skater he has a Display Object Container (Movie Clip) in it he has a Display Object a bitmap image of a skater and then an animation on the timeline in the skater where at the end the skater falls. On that last frame he has:

```
stop();
parent.restart();
```

He explains that this may not work and it doesnt he gets an error:

```
 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method restart through a reference with static type    flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.
```

He explains that it knows there is a stop() function on the main timeline, and that it knows there is a restart function on the main timeline, but the datatype is different. He also says that the parent is the main timeline.

He says that we need to put `Object(parent).restart();`

My question is of what datatype and what is the main timeline (Movieclip, DisplayObject, Display Object Container)?

Why would it be a different datatype?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main timeline is a MovieClip, or if you have a DocumentClass, then probably a custom type that at least extends MovieClip.

However when you ask for "parent" of your skater MovieClip, you are really using the parent property that MovieClip inherits from DisplayObject ([ActionScript Docs Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#parent)). This property returns the parent as type DisplayObjectContainer, regardless of the type that it actually is. Since it is the parent of a DisplayObject, it doesn't matter type it is it has to extend DisplayObjectContainer, so this is how it is returned.

So when you compile your ActionScript, the compiler looks at "parent" and sees it as type DisplayObjectContainer, looks at its definition of DisplayObjectContainer and errors because DisplayObjectContainer doesn't have a function called "restart".

What you said about the "stop" function is not really correct, since you are not calling stop on the main timeline, your are calling stop on the Skater's timeline. If you wanted to call stop on the main timeline you would need to call parent.stop(), and this would give you the same error, since DisplayObjectContainer doesn't have a method called stop.

These are both compiler errors, and are caused because the compiler is following a set of rules, and it can't make assumptions about what might actually happen when your program is running. It just knows that when you call parent.restart() it might receive a DisplayObjectContainer that won't have the method restart on it, and a run-time error will occur.

Now, by casting parent as type object, you are effectively telling that compiler that this thing can have any method or property on it, since Object is a dynamic class. So the compiler will now assume that you as the developer know that the method "restart" will exists on the "Object" that is given to that bit of code, and therefor will not error any more.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for you reply. This is really confusing. I thought that DisplayObjectContainer is a subclass of Display Object and it extends it? I know that Display Object Container is a Display Object and it can contain other Display objects and Display Object Containers. So the way I understand it, the maintimeline is a movieclip and therefore a DisplayObejctContainer, which can contain other Display objects (that you create in you application) and that is why parent returns Display Object Container, but that it is also a abstract class which means that it cannot have methods such as .restart and goToAndPlay() because it cannot actually be instantiated. However if its a MovieClip as you say then it can..... I dont get it.Does it mean that it is an abstract Class?